# Leading spaces are not preserved when pasting text

Tags: indentation, texstudio

In TeXstudio, if I paste lines of text that contain leading spaces, they are altered automatically by the editor producing an undesirable layout.

MWE: Copy the following snippet and paste it in the editor.

```
\begin{verbatim}
    1
  -----
  s + 1
\end{verbatim}
```

This is how it looks after pasting:

```
\begin{verbatim}
1
-----
s + 1
\end{verbatim}
```

- Why is this happening?
- How can I keep the indentation of the pasted text intact?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

TeXstudio offers three indentation modes:

- **Ignore Indentation:** turns auto-indentation off.
- **Keep Indentation:** copies the indentation from the previous line.
- **Indent and Unindent Automatically:** re-indents text automatically to match the context.

From the [TeXstudio User Manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION01):

> The selection box "Indentation mode" lets you select, wether indented
>   lines are followed by lines of the same indentation after pressing
>   Enter or letting TeXstudio do automatic indentation.

*"Indent and Unindent Automatically"* mode is enabled by default. Since you want to preserve the indentation of the text you need to change this setting to *"Ignore Indentation"*.

Go to `Options` > `Configure TeXstudio` > `Editor`

[image: TeXstudio indentation mode]

Other sources:

- https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1696/
- https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1698/
- https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/151/
- https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907840/thread/c43ddd0d/

Comment: It's quite unfortunate there is no way to disable auto-indentation when pasting but keep automatic indentation when typing in the editor.

Comment: I think the 'Keep Indentation' option is essentially this @eregon